# New definition of Expander graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraphs

The answer to the following question could be **trivial**!

**Introduction:**

[Expander graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph) is a sparse graph that has strong connectivity properties.

In this [book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/expander-families-and-cayley-graphs-9780199767113?cc=fr&lang=en&) or  [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/expander_survey.pdf).  Expanders are defined only for the graph case.

**Question:**

Are expander graph are defined  for hypergraphs ? and if so, is there already known work in this direction ?

The new definition of expanders could be: That is  $(G_n)$ will be sequence of **hypergraph**, where $|G_n|\rightarrow \infty $ as $n\rightarrow \infty $, and $\exists \epsilon\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $h(G_n)\geq \epsilon$

Any idea will be useful!